# Mysql on duplicate key replace all

Tags: mysql

I have a table `T1`:

```
 Col1 | Col2
-------------
  a   |   2
  b   |   3
```

If `Col1` is unique and `Col2` is not then I can run the query:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (b,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

and the table now looks like this:

```
 Col1 | Col2
-------------
  a   |   2
  b   |   2
```

If `Col1` and `Col2` are both unique I would like to run a *single* query:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (b,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY -- REPLACE ALL INSTANCES ?
Col1 = VALUES(Col1), Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

which results in this:

```
 Col1 | Col2
-------------
  b   |   2
```

So the key "b" is now associated with the key "2", replacing both "a"'s association and "b"'s previous association.

Is there a mysql query or extension that can accomplish this? (Clearly this can be done with multiple queries, I'm looking for an analogue of the `ON DUPLICATE` extension for this use case.)

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while, I'm pretty certain that this cannot be done. There is no mention of anything other than `UPDATE` or `IGNORE` for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in the manual. The requested action is tantamount to doing a `DELETE` inside an `UPDATE` statement. (Which you cannot do).

The following code performs the task, I don't like having to wrap it in a transaction but it is the only way to do it at the moment.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE Col2 = 2 AND Col1 <> "b"; -- Without checking Col1 the row will be replaced instead of updated if the entry ("b",2) already exists
INSERT INTO t1 (Col1, Col2)
VALUES("b",2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Col2 = VALUES(Col2);
COMMIT;
```